# How can I create a vertical separator bar between a form's Label and Field implemented in UITableView?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to implement a form much like the iPad's Data Plan Registration form.  I am having a problem creating the vertical separator between my form's Labels and Fields.  In the example below I'm trying to implement the vertical field/label separator in each section.  Thanks for any help.  I've searched the forums and looked at lots of tutorials, but have found none that address this specific question.

My Example will be weak since I'm not allowed to post an image...

```
Using UITableView...
---------------------------------------------
   First Name   |  UITextField             
---------------------------------------------
   Last Name    |  UITextField             
---------------------------------------------
```

Thanks again for reading this post.
GuyT

Comment: So far, I have created my popup form.  I have my UITableView, with grouped sections.  I have tried it with setting the UITableViewCellStyle to Left Detail (That all gets me close but still missing the vertical).  I'm currently going to try adding an image view.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve and answer my own question.  It ended up being pretty easy to do, and I had seen the recommendation somewhere else (I'd love to give credit to the person that made the suggestion, but I can't remember where I read it now.  Sorry).

Comment: Glad you've solved it. You should answer your own question, it'll be more readable than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the recommendation from M42 I wanted to provide the answer that I used for my question.

My solution comes by using UITableViewCellStyle set to Custom.  To implement a custom layout, first you will need to create a PNG image 5px x 200px to create a vertical separator line.  When creating the image, be sure to choose a line color that will match the UITableView Cell Lines.  Once created, add the PNG file to your project and then customize the cell layout by adding a UILabel, a UIImageView and a UITextField.  Set the UIImageView's image property to the image you created.  Be sure the image view reaches the top and bottom edge of your cell lines.